# 2 tables in one page, However, only the first table has the search and pagination in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make 2 tables in the page. It works, however the second table does not have a search and pagination.

How do I add search and pagination to the 2nd table.

[Here is the code](http://i.stack.imgu)

[Printscreen of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiHNz.png)

Comment: Your source code is no longer accesible. You should paste it here, or provide a valid fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need define your second table as data table like this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
    $('#myTable1').dataTable();
    });
```